# "Thank you Andy and Sandy", do I thank Sandy more or Andy more?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-order, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

I want to thank two people in my thank you email. In particular, I want to thank Sandy more because she has helped me a lot. So, if I say "Thank you Andy and Sandy", does the placement of the two names matter? According to my friend, the position after "And" places more emphasis than the position before and.

So, if I say "Thank you Andy and Sandy", do I mean I want to thank Sandy more?

Comment: No. In fact, if you wanted to thank Sandy any **less**, then a comma might play a trick: "Thank you Andy, and Sandy." Ha ha!

Comment: Please ask your friend to substantiate.

Comment: If you had a list of ten names, not in obvious order by alphabet, department, etc, then being named near the end would tend to infer less importance.  But with fewer than about five names this is not the case, and, in fact, the last name may be (but isn't necessarily)  considered the most important.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I see And as an operator that links the objects on either side. It parallels the operator + in 1+2, which is identical to 2+1. From this perspective it implies no particular order; in mathematical terms it is commutative. Andy and Sandy enjoy equal status in such a sentence. But, be careful! Where the linked objects are more complex, the operator can become non-communative and meaning can change. I stabbed him and he died. He died and I stabbed him.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on suggesting *inequality* using just placement in such a simple phrase. If only because there are many people trying to imply *equal* weighting to the elements in the same construction.

Kris's comment [reversing the names] "Thank you Sandy, and Andy" works well, I think: the comma implying that Andy was rather an afterthought in your thanks.

But, and this might be important to you, do you really want to tell both Andy and Sandy (in a joint email) that you value the contribution (frienship?) of one more than the other? It might be more diplomatic to write at greater length, thanking them individually for what they have done. If Sandy has done more, then it's obvious in that context.

Or send them individual emails, where you can be more specific and effusive in your thanks to one of them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to thank Sandy more and do it publicly, this is often done:

> Thank you Andy and, especially, Sandy.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Heisenberg question, the answer to which will depend upon the observer/respondent. Order in a list of terms joined by a single conjunction is sometimes presumed ordered to indicate importance, and writers will sometimes attempt to restore parity by ordering a list alphabetically (implying that the terms are otherwise equal) or by adding a phrase like "in no special order."

Yet there is another way of looking at the terms. The conjunction *and* evokes one of those constructs in which, for the sake of style, every term should be a member of some implied class.

Another example of a construct calling for parity among its members lies in the use of a comparative adjective. Consider this famous quote from Mother Teresa:

**It is better to light a candle than to curse the darkness.**

The comparative adjective is better, and the object of comparison is the infinitive of a transitive verb followed by that infinitive's object. Likewise, the marker for the thing to which the object is compared, *than*, is also immediately followed by the infinitive of a transitive verb followed by that infinitive's object. The parallels extend beyond the  grammar and into the connotations: light/curse are instances of the class of reactions to a problem: one brings light, and the other takes it away. And of course a candle, a metaphor for hope, is the opposite of darkness, hopelessness, and the two are instances of the class of fundamental cosmic conditions: yin and yang, good and evil, hope and hopelessness.

A series of terms joined by a single conjunction have their relationship implied by that conjunction. If the conjunction is *so*, then the relationship is one of consequence: the last term is a result of the preceding terms. If the conjunction is *but*, then the last term is an exception to the preceding terms. If the conjunction is *then*, the last term is the last event in a sequence of events listed by the terms. But if the conjunction is *and*, then the terms have parity among themselves and no one term takes precedence over the other: this is an egalitarian list, and Andy and Sandy earned your thanks equally.

What matters even more than how you list the couple in that introductory sentence is what you say afterwards:

> Thank you Andy and Sandy for helping me move last weekend. Andy's
>   muscle was indispensable in getting that couch up onto my second-floor
>   balcony when it would not fit through the front door, and his humor
>   and superb tastes in imported beer made the move seem more like a
>   party than a chore. Sandy likewise lifted the spirits of the movers
>   with her happy positivism, and she took upon herself the daunting task
>   of sorting the silver and crystal upon arrival after making sure
>   nothing broke on the way over. I cannot thank either of you enough,
>   and each of you contributed so much in his or her own way that I'm
>   really not sure whom to thank first.